# How to add click to items with same classes in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript

I don't know how I can catch individual elements with the same classes in pure javascript (without jQuery).

example:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="divInside"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="divInside"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="divInside"></div>
</div>
```

Specifically, I want to catch a "divInside" for the "item" so that I can add a click function. Can someone help me?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll('.divInside')` will get you a list of all the elements in the document with the `divInside` class.

Adding a click event to all of them should be as easy as this:

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.divInside')

elems.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', e => {
//Whatever you want to do
}))
```

What `querySelectorAll` does is it essentially lets you search for elements on the DOM using a matching CSS selector. If you want to get just the first element that matches a selector, you can use `document.querySelector` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have 1 more question: If I have input hidden with the id next to "divInside" inside "item", how can I take value of this?

Comment: The css selector would be `#divInside`, so you can do `document.querySelector('#divInside').value`

Answer (score 0):

You would use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) followed by [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through and add the click events.

```js
function clickEvent(e){
   console.log(e);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.item > .divInside').forEach((div)=>{
        div.addEventListener('click', clickEvent);
    });
});
```